# Cadena de Conexión para Cuenta de Servicio - Autenticación de Windows C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, consola, conexión

Quiero conectarme a una base de datos de SQL en un programa de consola en c# que estoy realizando pero tengo el problema de que la base de datos esta en un servidor y para conectarme tengo una cuenta de servicio con su usuario y contraseña que para conectarme desde SQL Server necesito darle Shift + click derecho y ejectutar SQL con un diferente usuario e ingresar mi cuenta de servicio, entonces la pregunta aqui es como puedo conectarme a esta base de datos desde C#, intente esto pero me arroja un error de que fallo en logear el usuario:

```
 try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "Servidor",
                    UserID = "usuario",
                    Password = "contraseña",
                    InitialCatalog = "base de datos"
                };
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Conexion a base de datos");
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM Tabla";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
```

Talvez este haciendo mal mi cadena de conexion o talvez sea por la cuenta de servicio no lo se, pido su ayuda para saber que puedo hacer... Gracias!

[image: Error]

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error?

Comment: Deje una imagen con el error

Comment: El error tambien como texto!!!! por fuera, desde donde ejecutas la consola, no podes entonces conectarte??? suena a que hiciste lio con los usuarios.. tu sql server acepta conexiones remotas???

Comment: @gbianchi No, no puedo conectarme y sí mi SQL acepta conexiones remotas porque como comente yo en mi sql server para conectarme a la base de datos tengo que hacer el proceso que mencione y no tengo problemas, y quiero saber como se hace una cadena de conexion de una cuenta de servicio o saber porque tengo ese error

Comment: En otras palabras, crea un usuario y asigna los permisos sobre la base de datos que necesitas usar. Utiliza dicho usuario en tu aplicación. Saludos.

Comment: Pero ya tengo mi usario con su respectivo permiso, que es el que me marca el error de que falló en ingresar

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una usuario y darle los permisos necesario, para abrir la conexión y  a la base respectiva que vas a consumir.

[image: Aquí debes crear el login]